# close case layout not showing for closed case

Tags: page-layout, case

When closing a case I don't get redirected to the Closed Case layout.
I have selected the 'Closed' status as Close in the picklist values and assigned the Close Cases layout to the users.

Any idea on why this is happening? Should I select another setting I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you check if the 'Close Case Layout' is assigned correctly ?
You can do this by going to Setup > Customize > Cases > Page Layouts and click the 'Page Layout Assignment'

FYI : The 'Close case layout' is rendered when you click the 'Close Case' standard button on the case detail page. it's not a detail page layout specific to the closed cases. if you want to do this I'm afraid you have to use Recordtype/Page layout assignment

Comment: Yes, it is assigned for all my profiles.

Comment: So when you hit 'Close Case' button on the case layout you aren't redirected to the 'Close case layout' ? then how you are changing the picklist status?

Comment: No, I do and I'm able to change the status by picklist, but when the Case is closed and I go to its detail page, I don't see the Close Case Layout but the Normal Layout with the Close Case button.

Comment: oh, ok! Is it right that I also see the Close Case button anyway? Thank you, I really did not understand this.

Comment: I'm moving my comment to the answer. upvote or choose it as an answer if this helps you